# Paw paw tree fruit

Tags: trees

I have many paw paw trees growing in my back yard in northern Indiana. Of all the trees only one is bearing fruit. Is there anything I can do to help the others to bear fruit?[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asimina_triloba) says the most common cause of poor fruiting is

> Pawpaw flowers are insect-pollinated, but fruit production is
>   sometimes limited as few if any pollinators are attracted to the
>   flower's faint, or sometimes non-existent scent.[22] The flowers
>   produce an odor similar to that of rotting meat to attract blowflies
>   or carrion beetles for cross pollination. Other insects that are
>   attracted to pawpaw flowers include scavenging fruit flies, carrion
>   flies and beetles. Because of irregular fruit production, some believe
>   pawpaw plants are self-incompatible, requiring cross-pollination
>   between trees of different clones (patches).

It then goes on to indicate that dedicated growers

> often resort to hand pollination or to use of pollinator attractants
>   such as spraying fish emulsion or hanging chicken necks or other meat
>   near the open flowers to attract pollinators.

Despite the good taste and yield of the fruit members of my house would not stand for hanging meat in trees so I wish you luck!

Consulting with your local gardening society or extension service will provide you with local information.